# Multiple windows handling with VBA and VB.NET API

Tags: vba, excel, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to use API with below VBA code, but there are  `multiple windows handle` with same caption and class name like "#32770" and "Button". So, how can I move on to next handle. I have attached the screen shot of spy registry values I wanted to access second window handle with multiple button caption but they also have same window caption and class name.

[image: screenshot]

Please refer attached screen shot for multiple windows handle.

```
Sub sbRunCalcUsingAPI()

 hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Calculator")

    start_doc = ShellExecute(hwnd, "open", "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe", 0, 0, SW_NORMAL)

    If start_doc = 2 Then Exit Sub
    If start_doc = 3 Then Exit Sub

    Do
    DoEvents
    hWnd2 = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Calculator")
    Loop Until hWnd2 > 0

    main_view = FindWindowEx(hWnd2, 0&, "CalcFrame", vbNullString) 
    sub_window2 = FindWindowEx(main_view, X&, "#32770", vbNullString)
    sub_window2One = FindWindowEx(main_view, 0&, "Button", vbNullString)

End Sub
```

Comment: Guyz, please address above query asap....

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use 'GetNextWindow() instead of 'FindWindowEx() here.
Now you have one of three options: First Child Window, Next Child Window,
or Previous Child Window.
Every case is unique, and your approach may need some tweaking depending
on your element's attributes.
Personally, I use this when the class or window caption is ambiguous.
I look for a unique window label above or below the ambiguous one
and then find the hwnd using one of the options.

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long _
    ) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
    ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
    ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
    ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
    ByVal lpsz2 As String _
    ) As Long

 Public Declare Function GetNextWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindow" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wFlag As Long _
    ) As Long

Public Const GW_HWNDFIRST = 0
Public Const GW_HWNDPREV = 1
Public Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Public Const SW_NORMAL As Long = 1


Sub sbRunCalcUsingAPI()

    Dim x As Long

'You do not need 'Let hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Calculator") '
'if you are opening it for the first time.
'It is used in cases where you want to open a 'tabbed window', like Internet Explorer.
'You would then find the parent window and open a new tab in it. For your purpose,
'you can leave it blank."

      '  Let hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Calculator")

        start_doc = ShellExecute( _
                                0&, _
                                "open", _
                                "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe", _
                                0, _
                                0, _
                                SW_NORMAL _
                                )

        If start_doc = 2 Then Exit Sub
        If start_doc = 3 Then Exit Sub

        Do
            DoEvents
            Let hWnd2 = FindWindow( _
                                    vbNullString, _
                                    "Calculator" _
                                    )
        Loop Until hWnd2 > 0

        Let main_view = FindWindowEx( _
                                    hWnd2, _
                                    0&, _
                                    "CalcFrame", _
                                    vbNullString _
                                    )

        Let sub_window2 = FindWindowEx( _
                                    main_view, _
                                    x&, _
                                    "#32770", _
                                    vbNullString _
                                    )


'You will want to use 'GetNextWindow() instead of 'FindWindowEx() here.
'Now you have one of three options: First Child Window, Next Child Window,
'or Previous Child Window
'Every case is unique, and your approach may need some tweaking depending
'on your element's attributes.
'Personally, I use this when the class or window caption is ambiguous.
'I look for a unique window label above or below the ambiguous one
'and then find the hwnd using one of the options.

       ' Let sub_window2One = FindWindowEx(main_view, 0&, "Button", vbNullString)

    'First Child Window
    Let sub_window2One = GetNextWindow( _
                                        sub_window2, _
                                        GW_HWNDFIRST _
                                        )
    'Previous Child Window
    Let VIP_6_Digit_hwnd = GetNextWindow( _
                                        sub_window2, _
                                        GW_HWNDPREV _
                                        )
    'Next Child Window
    Let VIP_6_Digit_hwnd = GetNextWindow( _
                                        sub_window2, _
                                        GW_HWNDNEXT _
                                        )

End Sub
```